# Why does a DynamoDB item update with an update expression cause a 500 InternalFailure & a 30 second hang?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting a `500 Internal Error` when trying to perform an update using an `UpdateExpression` using the Node.js AWS SDK (`AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`).

The operation hangs for about 30 seconds and then returns this error:

```
InternalFailure: null
    at Request.extractError (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (WORKSPACE/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InternalFailure',
  time: 2021-10-08T16:24:49.756Z,
  requestId: 'EJJH7IIRFCS0HOPNQ9IIS39CKJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 500,
  retryable: true
}
```

I get this both when running my code in a Lambda function as well as when running locally using the DynamoDB REST API (so it's not a Lambda permission issue).

What's causing this internal error?

My code to update the item:

```
export async function addOverride(addOverrideRequest: any) {
    const addListIfNotExists = {
        TableName: addOverrideRequest.table,
        Key: {
            Environment: addOverrideRequest.environment
        },
        UpdateExpression: "SET Overrides.:overrideAttr = :emptylist",
        ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(Overrides.:overrideAttr)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":overrideAttr": addOverrideRequest.overrideField,
            ":emptylist": [],
          },
    }

    try {
        const result = await DOCUMENT_CLIENT.update(addListIfNotExists).promise();
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

The request resolves as:

```
{
  TableName: 'AppVersions',
  Key: { Environment: 'int' },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET Overrides.:overrideAttr = :emptylist',
  ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(Overrides.:overrideAttr)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':overrideAttr': 'EyeTrackerType', ':emptylist': [] }
}
```

Comment: Does retrying the request work? It's marked as retryable

Comment: Retrying failed with the same error :(.

Comment: Okay - try `UpdateExpression: "SET Overrides.EyeTrackerType = :emptylist"` & then remove `":overrideAttr": addOverrideRequest.overrideField,` as in hard code the nested object property name - does that solve the issue?

Comment: Yes! I also had to change the condition. I will explore in this direction by assembling those values myself. What do you think the base issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ExpressionAttributeNames`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html) to define your attribute names, instead of adding them to `ExpressionAttributeValues`.

---

*ExpressionAttribute**Names*** are used to specify dynamic attribute names, however, you're specifying `overrideAttr` inside *ExpressionAttribute**Values***.

Also, you must use the hash sign - `#` - for indicating placeholders for attribute names.

This should work:

```
const addListIfNotExists = {
    TableName: addOverrideRequest.table,
    Key: {
        Environment: addOverrideRequest.environment
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET Overrides.#overrideAttr = :emptylist",
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(Overrides.#overrideAttr)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#overrideAttr": addOverrideRequest.overrideField
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":emptylist": []
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate yout ime :).

Comment: No worries, you're welcome!

Comment: Although the request has a bunch of syntax mistakes, as others correctly pointed out, it's interesting that DynamoDB reports a retryable "internal error" instead of a non-retryable ValidationException as it should. I guess it's a parser bug..

Comment: @NadavHar'El The request I've posted should be fine syntax wise - have I missed anything? But yes - it is interesting as it's not really retryable :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your mistake was using :overrideAttr instead of #overrideAttr. That's a syntax mistake or validation error or whatever you want to call it and it is pointless to retry - it's not a retryable "internal error" like Dynamo gave you.